# Animate Bitmap to Move on a Curve

Tags: android, bitmap, android-animation

How would I animate a bitmap in android so that it moves across the screen in a parabolic arch or any other curved path? Currently, the method I'm using is to use the onDraw() method to draw a bitmap to the canvas with an x/y coordinate and then increasing that x/y coordinate by one after the bitmap has been drawn, at which point the method calls invalidate() to redraw the bitmap with the new position.

Update:

Maybe this will give a bit more context to what i'm trying to do. Below is the implementation I have right now for animating my bitmap:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
canvas.drawBitmap(gBall, x, y, null);

x += changeX;
y += changeY;

if(x >= (canvas.getWidth()-gBall.getWidth()) || x <= 0)
    changeX = -changeX;
if(y >= (canvas.getHeight()-gBall.getHeight()) || y <= 0)
    changeY = -changeY;


invalidate();
```

Is there a way while still using this implementation to make the bitmap gBall curves as it approaches the edge of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler to controle the speed :

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, ...){
   if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCall < PERIOD-50){
       mHandler.postDelayed(mReDrawRunnable,PERIOD);
       return;
   }

   //to call back
   mHandler.removeCallbacks(mReDrawRunnable);
   mHandler.postDelayed(mReDrawRunnable,PERIOD);
   lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();

   //your code here
   ...


}
private long lastCall = 0;
private static final PERIOD = 250; //millis
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mReDrawRunnable==new Runnable() {
          public void run() {YourClass.this.invalidate();}
        };
```

This is a quick way to do it, it should work. You should create an other thread to control the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom Animator. To implement a custom animator, all you have to do is overide the applyTransformation method of the Animator class. You can then call View.startAnimation with an instance of your custom class. Given the lengths that google developers have gone to to implement smooth animations, this is likely to be the best solution -- much better than performing actions off a handler, which is likely to cause glitches due to garbage collects. A properly implmement Animation, that performs no memory allocations in its applyTransform method can run without incurring any garbage collects at all.

If you look at platform sources, it quickly becomes apparent that glitch-free animations were a primary development goal in Android 4.x. Google engineers have put a lot of work in to making sure that Animations run without glitches. Your draw-and-invalidate strategy may actually work plausibly well. The Handler approach not so much. But if it were me, I'd take the extra time to leverage the effort that has been put into Animations.